# Getting Information from TMDB

Tags: jquery, html, json, each, themoviedb-api

Currently I am stuck I want to return the title, plot and poster using themoviedb api I have no idea how to start the coding for this

Currently when i run a search the information is display in the console log of the browser i want to take that information and style it into a table format nothing fancy just the title and poster need help no clue where to start

doc site here http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#get-%2F3%2Fsearch%2Fmovie

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample Seach</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/',
    mode = 'search/movie',
    input,
    movieName,
    key = '?api_key=My API KEY HERE';

    $('button').click(function() {
        var input = $('#movie').val(),
            movieName = encodeURI(input);
        $.ajax({
            url: url + mode + key + '&query='+movieName ,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data) {
             console.log(data);

            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="movie" type="text" /><button>Search</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you are trying to do it too fast. Wrap your function with `$(document).ready(...)`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/',
    mode = 'search/movie',
    input,
    movieName,
    key = '?api_key=api key here';

    $('button').click(function() {
        var input = $('#movie').val(),
            movieName = encodeURI(input);
        $.ajax({
            url: url + mode + key + '&query='+movieName ,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data) {
             console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
             alert(status + ", " + error);
            }
        });
    });
});

<input id="movie" type="text" /><button>Search</button>
```

Comment: can u show me how to do a $(document).ready(...) fucntion i im new to jquery and all that ?

Comment: didnt work i have edited my above code maybe u can see if i did it wrong and do u know how i can get it to display in a div

Comment: Seems like the problem is on the other side. Add `error` handler the same way as `success` and see what you're getting from the server.

Comment: change the code above again add the error handle still getting nothing

Comment: No, put the `error` handler right after the `success` handler. You've put it outside of `ajax` call. I've edited my answer to show you where it should be.

Comment: Edited the way u said still nothing there is a link to another question that was answer asking the same thing they have jsfiddles but none of them work anymore thats way i asked this again really need help getting this working ? thanks for all ur input so far tho u got anything else ?

Comment: u would mind pointing out where ? alos i have add the example from there site they have two could they be of help

Comment: This is the error in the console Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Comment: @Jamiex304 Between your success and error functions. Just compare your code with the Elmo's answer.

Comment: i have been able to fix it so i can no see the results in console in my browers i am no stuck on how to display them on the page any example u have is welcome the above code is the working one

Comment: it was not nessessery your original fixed work it was my fault for not fixing my code sry no i am just looking for help getting the imformation from the console to the page itself so it can be viewed all i want it the title and poster for each one any idea's?

Comment: Please, accept the answer then if you don't mind :) And ask another question about the new problem you have.

Comment: rewrote the question above any idea on it